# Django with redis is caching all pages

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-redis

I'm using template cache with django-redis and it works properly but, although I don't use decorators (like cache_page, cache_control etc..), django is caching automatically every loaded page.

I verified this using redis-cli. This is `keys *` output after page load:

```
1) ":1:views.decorators.cache.cache_header..11786bb66822aef24b9fe0dac22e6e4e..."
2) ":1:views.decorators.cache.cache_page..GET.11786bb66822aef24b9fe0dac22e6e4e..."
3) ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cached_db8ss2k5s9jmp42cer0fs1nd..."
```

I tried to use never_cache on every view and it works but I don't see that as a good solution.
There's a better way?

My configuration is simple

```
CACHES = {
    'default':
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
            'LOCATION': 'redis://redis_ip:redis_port',
            'TIMEOUT': 60
        },
}
```

MIDDLEWARE.PY

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     ...
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    ...]
```

Thanks to all

Comment: can you show your MIDDLEWARE settings related to cache?

Comment: I updated with middleware and redis-cli output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `UpdateCacheMiddleware` and `FetchFromCacheMiddleware` from your `MIDDLEWARE` settings. They are meant for [per-site caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache), so every page is cached when you have those middleware.